# GeoServer - page not found http error 404

Tags: geoserver

I have an html file with the arcgis api for js on it stored in the following location:

C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.10.5\webapps\agis_api\js.html

I'm running GeoServer on port 8080 localhost for development and am using the following url to view the page:

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/agis_api/js.html

I'm getting error 404 not found. GeoServer is definitely running. Not sure why the page isn't coming up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not found because the URL is wrong, you are creating a new application **next** to GeoServer rather than under it. So your URL should be:

```
http://localhost:8080/agis_api/js.html
```

Comment: Thank you. It's been a minute since I've made an html page in the webapps dir.